# Jest is throwing Error: expect(received).toThrow()

Tags: javascript, jestjs, throw

I have class Person constructor(state, uid). State can only have two values "active" and "inactive".
this is how setState function looks like

```
setState(value) {

    if (value === "active" || "inactive") {
      this._state = value
    } else {
      throw new Error("error")
    }
  }
```

and Jest is throwing error

```
Error: expect(received).toThrow()

Received function did not throw
```

this is the line where error occurs

```
expect(() =>  p1.setState("bla")).toThrow();
```

How can I rewrite setState function, so that Jest registers the error.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in the if statement expression. This is how it should be:

```
if (value === 'active' || value === 'inactive') {
```

In your code, the right side of the `or` operator is a string constant, which will always evaluate to true.